# Are primitive questions suitable for the site?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am currently learning Modern Hebrew but I am still a complete novice.

Since I am learning on my own, I have to answer the questions I have asked myself. Yet, I do not always have an answer and need some help. To be more precise, I am not speaking of questions like "how does X translate from Hebrew into English" but some primitive problems concerning syntax and morphology (mostly the latter).

I've already asked one such [question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/36180/hebrew-root-%D7%90%D7%94%D7%91), yet I'm not sure whether I should keep on clogging the site with problems of that sort.

Are such questions welcome on Linguistics.SE or should I consider [LL.SE](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/) or someplace else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no primitive questions, just simple questions. Simple / elementary questions are encouraged, especially clear ones. This site is about linguistics, not language learning, so the question should be a linguistic one, but that question about the underlying root is appropriate, though it does call for specialized knowledge (but, you got an answer). It's difficult to succinctly characterize the difference between a language-learning question and a linguistic question about a language, but if you can make the question be something general about the structure of the language, or how to analyze a general construction in the language, and isn't just a translation request, then the question is more likely to pass the "language specific" filter.

Comment: Though I, at least, would welcome any question showing signs of demonstrating that linguistics might not be totally useless to non-linguists.